# Is there a way to solve two linear equations in python without the use of any module?

Tags: python, linear-equation

Is there any way of solving two linear equations simultaneously in python without the use of a module??
I want to solve these two equations but can't seem to find the approach .

```
                         a - b = 1
                         a + b = 5
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: although it is not relevant but still the solution would be: a=3 and b=2

Comment: of course it is possible, but you have to represent that algebraic expression in terms of python syntax.

Comment: yep the representation i want help with

Comment: use tokenize from python stdlib. this will tokenize expressions so you can read and parse them to more relevant structure. https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you made any effort whatsoever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need linear algebra module such as numpy.

```
#e.g. 
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1,-1], [1,1]])
y = np.array([1,5])
np.linalg.inv(X).dot(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement [Gauss Jordan elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). Its not a great way to do it, but for two equations a simple analytical solution will pop out.

Comment: will it work for more than two variables and more than two equations?